# My if statements are not giving me my desired result

Tags: python, if-statement

When the user input is anything, then it just prints my if statement that is if the user input is summer. If it is winter, then it just prints summer.

```
print ('Hello world')
print('What is your name')
myName = input()
print('It is good to meet you, ' +myName)
print ('Do you like winter or summer the best? ' +myName)
season = input()

if season == 'summer' or 'Summer':
    print('I like summer the best as well')
    print('Do you ever find that summer is too hot?')
    hot = input()

    if hot == 'no' or 'No' or 'n' or 'N':
        print('Me either. You will never hear me complain')
        print('about the weather being too hot in the summer time.')
    if hot == ('yes'):
        print('''I find that interseting. You said that you find summer to be too
hot but yet you also said that summer was you favourite time of year.''')

if season == 'winter' or 'Winter': 
    print('Don\'t you find winter too cold?')
    cold = input()

    if cold == 'No' or 'no' or 'N' or 'n':
        print('I think you are crazy/ I don\'t know how you stay warm')

        print('It\'s been nice chatting with you ' +myName)
        print('I hope we get the chance to chat again soon, I must go now')
        print('Good bye')
    if cold == 'yes' or 'Yes':
        print('I agree, but I still don\'t understand why you would like winter better than summer')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the way how boolean arithmetic in python works.

```
season == 'summer' or 'Summer'
```

is always true, because a non-empty string like 'Summer' is evaluated as true.

Try

```
if season in ('summer', 'Summer'):
```

or

```
if season.lower() == 'summer':
```

or alike...